# Embed resources in winform publish project

Tags: c#, winforms

So, i have a Winforms project containing a file that must be use as a resource.

Its properties are Embed resource and copy always.

Then when I publish my Winforms, it does not have the resource file, and can't use it.

Why don't I see this file in my publish project?

I got :

```
    setup.exe
    myapp.application
    Folder Application Files 

                    -my app 1_0_0_1
                    -my app 1_0_0_2
                                   _myapp/application
                                   _myapp.exe.config.deploy
                                   _myapp.exe.deploy
                                   _myapp.exe.manifest
```

How can I add, in my published project, a file (path myres/resource.csv)?

I was thinking, it will be published with the whole project, because  it is as embed resource and copy always.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded resource are built into your exe/dll, not as seperate files, much like a class or control. If you want to stick with an embedded resource, see this post on how to access it 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

If you want it to be a seperate file, make it a content file and then in your "publish files", make sure this file is selected, you may have to click on the "Show all files" option to see it.

Comment: Make sure my file is selected? What do  you mean? I got myres/resource.csv.deploy now. Is that what I should have?

Comment: From the info above, it appears you are doing a click-once publish, if not, ignore this. If so, on your project properties, goto the publish tab, click on Application Files. You can include files in your publish if you force it from here.

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual Studio try to change `BuildAction` of this file to `Contents` instead of `Embedded Resource`

Comment: Thank you. The other answer is more complete, so I will accept it. But still upvote for your.